# Guardar la posición de un puntero en otro

Tags: c++, punteros

Estoy intentando hacer un vector dinámico y tengo complicaciones con los punteros.

Para ello he creado un vector estático y tengo un puntero que apunta a su posición 0, como el resto de elementos del vector están en la posición +i mi idea es sumarle i a la posición de memoria de 0 para ir accediendo al resto de elementos. Al intentar esto me aparece un error no dejándome volcar la posición de memoria que tiene un vector en otro vector.

```
    class VDinamico {
private:
    int taml=0;
    int tamf=2;
    int *buffer;
public:
    VDinamico();
    VDinamico(const VDinamico& orig);
    int GetBuffer(int i) const {
        std::cout << "posicion 1::::"<<&buffer<<" posicion 2::::"<<&buffer+1<< std::endl;//prueba
        return ( *buffer );
    };
    void SetBuffer(int dato) 
    {
        int *temp=(&buffer+1); // <<--- AQUI!!!
        *buffer=dato;
    }

    virtual ~VDinamico();
};
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 5):

Si dadas las siguientes variables:

```
int a;
int b;
```

te pido que me copies el valor de `a` en `b`, ¿Cómo lo harías? Imagino que sería algo así:

```
b = a;
```

Vale, ahora vamos a cambiar el tipo de las variables:

```
int * a;
int * b;
```

Y te vuelvo a pedir que copies el valor de `a` en `b` ¿Cómo lo solucionamos ahora?

En tu código tu has intentado hacer algo tal que:

```
b = &a;
```

Lo cual, claramente, te va a dar un error en tiempo de compilación, porque la dirección de memoria de un puntero simple solo se puede gestionar con un puntero doble y un puntero doble no es lo mismo que un puntero simple:

```
int ** temp = &a;
b = temp; // int* = int** ¿?
```

La solución al segundo problema que te he planteado es exactamente la misma que la empleada en el primer problema:

```
b = a;
```

Y es que lo único que ha cambiado entre los dos problemas es que las variables `a` y `b` en vez de almacenar enteros han pasado a almacenar posiciones de memoria... pero las dos variables almacenan lo mismo y por eso son compatibles directamente... sin hacer cosas raras.

Otro cantar sería si tuvieses una variable `int` e intentases cargar su dirección de memoria en un puntero... entonces sí tendrías que usar el operador `&`:

```
int a;
int *b = &a;
```

Comment: Ese fue la solución a mi problema, muchas gracias! :D